# NameError when putting variable declaration in if __name__ == '__main__':

Tags: python, variables, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a Python file named `main.py`. I am running it on Python 3.9.13 on Windows.
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

```
app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/c')
async def c(b: str):
    print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = load_embeddings('embeddings')
    uvicorn.run('main:app', host='127.0.0.1', port=80)
```

Running this, then invoking POST /c will cause a 500 error with NameError 'a' is not defined.

However it is obvious that `a` will be defined first before the server is ran. If I move `a` outside of the `if __name__ == '__main__':` then it works, but it causes `load_embeddings` to be ran multiple times for unknown reasons (3 exact). Since `load_embeddings` for me takes long time, I do not want the duplicate execution.

I wish to look for either of these as a solution to my issue: stop whatever outside `if __name__ == '__main__':` from executing multiple times, OR make `a` defined globally when it is being defined under `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Note: variable names are intentionally renamed for ease of reading. Please do not advise me anything on coding style/naming conventions. I know the community is helpful but that's not the point here, thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you running this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue by moving the `a` variable definition inside the `c` function. Then, you can add a check inside the function to load the embeddings only if they have not been loaded yet. You can achieve this by using a global variable, which will keep track of whether the embeddings have been loaded or not.

Here is an example:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

EMBEDDINGS_LOADED = False

def load_embeddings(filename):
# Load embeddings code here
...

@app.post('/c')
async def c(b: str):
global EMBEDDINGS_LOADED
if not EMBEDDINGS_LOADED:
    load_embeddings('embeddings')
    EMBEDDINGS_LOADED = True
print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
uvicorn.run('main:app', host='127.0.0.1', port=80)
```

Comment: thanks, i have already implemented this as a workaround, but it adds unnecessary code that I do not wish to add - because I have tens of variables like `a` - cant do that for every place that needs it